# W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.*

Tags: android, react-native

I got this issue only for Android. For iOS everything working fine I have searched lot but not solve issue yet.

While running code on android platform Buttons displaying but not any views such as images, map etc or other thing.

Following is my console log:

```
V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/data/com.demo_mobile_app/lib-main
I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/data/com.demo_mobile_app/lib-main
V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/data/com.demo_mobile_app/lib-main
W/unknown:React: The packager does not seem to be running as we got an IOException requesting its status: Failed to connect to /10.0.2.2:8081
W/unknown:JSPackagerWebSocketClient: Couldn't connect to packager, will silently retry
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
I/art: Thread[1,tid=9074,WaitingForJniOnLoad,Thread*=0xf4025800,peer=0x73c5c000,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.demo_mobile_app-2/lib/x86/libfb.so"

   [ 10-08 11:02:33.564  9074: 9108 D/         ]
   HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf4365bb0, tid 9108
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf43fd9c0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTRenderableViewManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupShadowNode
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeShadowNode
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextShadowNode
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewShadowNode
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDialogPickerManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for  class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDropdownPickerManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.image.ReactImageManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ReactModalHostManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.modal.ModalHostShadowNode
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactRawTextManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextShadowNode
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$ReactSliderShadowNode
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowNode
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputShadowNode
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactTextViewManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.toolbar.ReactToolbarManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.viewpager.ReactViewPagerManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.ReactVirtualTextViewManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.webview.ReactWebViewManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.recyclerview.RecyclerViewBackedScrollViewManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.swiperefresh.SwipeRefreshLayoutManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapCalloutManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapMarkerManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapPolylineManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapPolygonManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapCircleManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapLiteManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapUrlTileManager
W/unknown:React: Unable to dispatch keyboard events in JS as the react instance has not been attached
I/ReactNativeJS: Running application "demo_mobile_app" with appParams: {"initialProps":{},"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.571ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7120(1669KB) AllocSpace objects, 22(307KB) LOS objects, 35% free, 3MB/5MB, paused 6.088ms total 13.686ms
W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.803ms
```

Comment: Hey, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager